# Mac Agent With El Capitan Can't Run Command line executables

Tags: teamcity

I upgraded our build agent to El Capital recently, and started getting some build failures for our builds.  Prior to the upgrade, I had no issues with any builds.

In my build configurations, I have a Command Line step configured to run an executable with parameters.  I use this step to run `pod install` prior to building the project.

On the version before El Capitan, this worked without issue.
On El Capitan though, I get this error: `Cannot run process pod install : file not found`

To me, it seems like it's trying to find an executable named `pod install`, not an executable `pod` with a parameter `install`.  If I remote to the Mac, I can freely type `pod install` with no issues in the terminal.

The workaround at the moment is to change the Command line type to a Custom Script, and put `pod install` in the script box, but I am curious if this is a bug with the Agent.

Comment: What is the TeamCity version you're running? What were the java versions on the agent machine before and after the upgrade to *El Capitan*?

Comment: @Bass  Apologies on the delay for the comment.  Team City Version is 9.0.2.  I'm unsure what version of Java was running before the upgrade.  Current version is `java version "1.8.0_05"`

Comment: Where the `pod` binary is located on your Mac box? Can you run other executables with arguments, like `ls -l` or `locale charmap`? Finally, TC 9.0.2 has been released quite a while ago (long before El Capitan) — can you upgrade to 9.1.4 instead?

Comment: `pod` binary is located in `/usr/local/bin` (default install place for gems now under El Capitan).  Upgrades are handled by a senior dev, so I'll request that we update and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: the default `PATH` of the user TC agent is running as, may be different from the custom `PATH` of your interactive session (different users may have different shells; interactive vs non-interactive and login vs non-login shells, in general, may exhibit different behavior). There's a chance `PATH` is missing `/usr/local/bin` entry entirely. What happens if you replace `pod install` with `/usr/local/bin/pod install`?

Comment: I actually already fixed that issue.  I had to add that path to the configuration for the agent.  The remaining issue is this: `Cannot run process pod install : file not found`.  It seems like its trying to find an executable `pod install`.  The fix is to make it a custom script, and place pod install in there.  I'm not sure why that behavior changed when I upgraded to El Capitan.